# Process blocks when accessing shared memory segment

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm working on a program that stores a `struct` in a shared memory segment so I can use the data in the main process and multiple `thread` simultaneously. I'm using also mutex semaphores (`pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()`) to guarantee mutual exclusion between processes that want to access that shared memory segment.

Firstly, a `thread` locks the `struct` and fills it with information:

```
void * client_thread(void *argc) {

    thread_input *t_input = (thread_input *) argc;  //struct that stores data usefull for the thread such as the shm segment

    shm_data *shmdata;   //<-- shared struct
    shmdata = shmat(t_input->memid, 0, 0);

    //...

    pthread_mutex_lock(t_input->mtx);
        shmdata->station = malloc((strlen(data.station)+1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(shmdata->station, data.station);
        shmdata->temperature = data.temperature;
        shmdata->humidity = data.humidity;
        shmdata->pressure = data.pressure;
        shmdata->precipitation = data.precipitation;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(t_input->mtx);

    //...
}
```

This works fine. Then, using a synchronization semaphore, `main` process tries to access that shared memory segment of a struct, for example trying to print first variable. But it gets blocked in that line:

**Main**

```
//...

shm_data *shmdata;  //<-- shared struct
shmdata = shmat(memid, 0, 0);

pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    write(1, "Station:\n", strlen("Station::")); //Prints fine
    write(1, shmdata->station, strlen(shmdata->station)); //<-- Program blocks here
    write(1, "Done!\n", strlen("Done!!")); //Program does not reach this point or any further
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);

//...
```

I have tested that the memory id in both `thread` and `main` process it's the same and I guarantee that `thread` code will execute first and then the `main` process. Why does the program get blocked there?

Comment: `shmdata->station` is allocated on heap thus it is shared between threads but **NOT** between processes. Only a pointer is shared but it is meaningless in other's process context. Try to make if a fixed size array defined in `shm_data` struct

Comment: @tstanisl shouldn't it work in this case though as I'm using threads?

Comment: did you initalize `mtx`?

Comment: Yes, using `pthread_mutex_t mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

Comment: I'll try changing it to a fixed size array, hope it works

Comment: If you are just using one process - with multiple threads - you do not need shared memory. Normal will do. Just use mutex to access it

Comment: @EdHeal I'm using shared memory because the thread is in a different module, not in the `main` process file. Can I still use mutex instead?

Comment: All threads share the same address space. It doesn't matter where and how the threads were spawned.

Comment: @tstanisl I changed `station` from `char *station`  to `char station[100]` in `shm_data` struct and I deleted the `malloc` so now I just use `strcpy(shmdata->station, data.station);` but I'm getting a segmentation fault core dumped in this line even though `data.station`'s length is just 8. Do you see any problem here?

Comment: Put the whole code into here. You can skip irrelevant parts as long as it compiles and produces the failure.

Comment: @tstanisl I found the error. Seems like I changed `station` to a fixed array in a different struct than in the one I was using smh... My bad. Thanks a lot

Comment: in the 'thread' function, regarding: `pthread_mutex_lock(t_input->mtx);
       ....
    pthread_mutex_lock(t_input->mtx);` The second call to `pthread_mutex_lock()` is not correct.  It should be: 'phread_mutex_unlock()`

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.